# PHP авторизация по сертификату

Tags: php, ssl

Возможно ли реализовать авторизацию на PHP используя имеющиеся сертификаты? Есть данные сертификатов ( серийные номера срок действия итд ). Как можно попросить пользователя выбрать сертификат и получить его данные в PHP?

Comment: На сколько мне известно, то сертификат можно поставить на Apache. http://r-notes.ru/administrirovanie/sluzhby/113-avtorizatsiya-po-ssl-sertifikatam.html

Comment: @ArchDemon требуется использовать имеющиеся сертификаты которые установлены на компьютерах.

Comment: И как это меняет суть ответа?

Comment: @ArchDemon согласно инструкции подразумевается создание дополнительных сертификатов и наличие их на стороне сервера. Что не возможно по причинам: 1. Требуется использовать имеющиеся сертификаты. 2. Самих сертификатов нет в наличии.

Comment: На сервере можно создать все сертификаты. Если имеется закрытый ключ, то можно собрать сертификат сервера совместимый с имеющимся клиентским (но что-то я сомневаюсь).